# Timeout during erlcoud SQS recieve Message

Tags: erlang, amazon-sqs

I am using [`erlcloud`](https://github.com/erlcloud/erlcloud) module for SQS use in Erlang. If i try:

```
erlcloud_sqs:receive_message("GamePackets").
```

it gives

```
{aws_error,{socket_error,timeout}}
```

But for other Queues it is working correctly. The said queue exist because i can see the queue attributes using:

```
erlcloud_sqs:get_queue_attributes("GamesPacket").
```